# Ошибка java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl

Tags: java, spring-mvc, soap, classcastexception

```
public static Valute getValuteByValuteCh(String valuteCh, GetCursOnDateXMLResult result) throws Exception{

    Valute answer = new Valute();

    List<Object> list = result.getContent();
    ElementNSImpl e = (ElementNSImpl) list.get(0);
    NodeList chCodeList =   e.getElementsByTagName("VchCode");
    int length = chCodeList.getLength();

    boolean isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i< length; i++){
        if (isFound) break;

        Node valuteChNode = chCodeList.item(i);
        TextImpl textimpl = (TextImpl)valuteChNode.getFirstChild();
        String chVal = textimpl.getData();

        if (chVal.equalsIgnoreCase(valuteCh)){
            isFound = true;
            Node parent = valuteChNode.getParentNode();
            NodeList nodeList = parent.getChildNodes();
            int paramLength = nodeList.getLength();

            for (int j=0; j<paramLength; j++){
                Node currentNode = nodeList.item(j);

                String name = currentNode.getNodeName();
                Node currentValue = currentNode.getFirstChild();
                String value = currentValue.getNodeValue();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Vname")){
                    answer.name = value;
                }
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Vnom")){
                    answer.nom = new BigDecimal(value);
                }
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Vcurs")){
                    answer.curs = new BigDecimal(value);
                }
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Vcode")){
                    answer.code = Integer.parseInt(value);
                }
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("VchCode")){
                    answer.chCode = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return answer;

}
```

Метод парсит XML ответ веб-сервиса цбрф.
Используется библиотека Xerces.

При запуске приложения на сервере возникает ошибка на строку `ElementNSImpl e = (ElementNSImpl) list.get(0);`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl at com.naitos.WSUsing.GetCursOnDateResultParser.getValuteByValuteCh(GetCursOnDateResultParser.java:44)
```

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, нужно заменить `import org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl` на `import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl`

Answer (score 0):

Тут видимо неправильный каст, а нужно

```
Element e = (Element) list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать интерфейс (Element) вместо реализации (ElementNSImpl) - тогда всё работает.